# Parse Error in css-loader sass-loader

Tags: webpack, css-loader, sass-loader, extract-text-plugin, webpack-3

I am migrating from webpack 1 to 3. After going through so many errors and now I am stuck on this. Can someone please **HELP**!

I am getting these errors -

```
ERROR in ./src/main/main.scss
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| body{
|     color: red;
| }
 @ ./src/main/js/App.jsx 13:0-23
 @ ./src/main/js/index.jsx
```

Here's the sample repo - https://github.com/shivamkumar110/webpack-3-test

and here is snippet from my *webpack.config.js*

```
module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            use: ['eslint-loader'],
            include: SRC,
            enforce: 'pre'
        },  {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            use: ['babel-loader'],
            include: SRC
        }, {
            test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
            include: SRC,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                        {
                        loader:'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap:true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing the `sass-loader`. What you can do is

1. Make sure the required loaders are installed as outlined in the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/).

   i.e run `npm install sass-loader node-sass css-loader style-loader --save-dev`

   That should fix the issue.
2. If not fixed after doing above, move local `node_modules` folder to a temporory location and then run `npm install`. This will get all the modules freshly.

   try running webpack again and it should **definitely** work.

Do let us know how it goes.

Hope that helps.

Rakesh

Comment: I have tried doing both.. and I am using sass-loader. Still not working. :(

Comment: @ShivamKumar Can you update OP to include your complete `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` ?

Comment: @ I have already provided the link to my repo - https://github.com/shivamkumar110/webpack-3-test

Comment: @ShivamKumar The webpack is configured to process the resources under `src/main/js`. The SCSS files are not located in that folder. Hence, the `sass-loader` is **not applicable** for them. Suggest to edit the webpack config to process resources from `src/main` instead.

Comment: Yes, that was also the issue. I fixed that. The other problem was the eslint config due to which build was failing

Answer (score 0):

Had the error below:
When executed "ng serve projectname"
Angular version 6

Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.

Solution:
Delete package-lock.json file and then run "npm install" this should update all dependencies.

Then, run the command below:
"npm install sass-loader node-sass css-loader style-loader --save-dev"